# How do I fix "numeric or value error" message?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle9i

I have been stuck with this issue now all morning. I actually saw this code here and decide to use it for our purpose here.

The issue that I am running into is that when we execute the code, sometimes it writes a file from db to the folder.

Other times, we get "numeric or value error"

Can any expert please help me fix it?

Here is the code I am using:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE getfile(pfname   VARCHAR2, display_name IN VARCHAR2)
IS
  vblob      BLOB;
  vstart     NUMBER := 1;
  bytelen    NUMBER := 32000;
  len        NUMBER;
  my_vr      RAW(32000);
  x          NUMBER;
  v_name     VARCHAR2(32760);
  lv_str_len NUMBER;
  l_output   utl_file.file_type;
BEGIN
  -- define output directory
  --lv_str_len := Length(pfname);

  --v_name := display_name||upper(substr(pfname,lv_str_len-3,lv_str_len));
  v_name := display_name;

  l_output := utl_file.Fopen('My_DIR', v_name, 'w', 32760);

  -- get length of blob
  SELECT dbms_lob.Getlength(FILENAME)
  INTO   len
  FROM   GENERAL.GUBFILE
  WHERE  gubfile_name = pfname;

  -- dbms_output.put_line('Length: '||len);
  -- save blob length
  x := len;

  -- select blob into variable
  SELECT BLOBVALUE
  INTO   vblob
  FROM   FILES
  WHERE  filename = pfname;

  -- if small enough for a single write
  IF len < 32760 THEN
    -- dbms_output.put_line('Single write ');
    utl_file.Put_raw(l_output, vblob);

    utl_file.Fflush(l_output);
  ELSE -- write in pieces
    -- dbms_output.put_line('multi write '||vstart);
    vstart := 1;

    WHILE vstart < len LOOP
        dbms_lob.READ(vblob, bytelen, vstart, my_vr);

        utl_file.Put_raw(l_output, my_vr);

        utl_file.Fflush(l_output);

        -- set the start position for the next cut
        vstart := vstart + bytelen;

        -- set the end position if less than 32000 bytes
        x := x - bytelen;

        IF x < 32000 THEN
          bytelen := x;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
  END IF;

  dbms_output.Put_line('End');

  utl_file.Fclose(l_output);
END getfile;
```

The exact error is:

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "USER.GETFILE", line 40
ORA-06512: at line 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from `utl_file.put_raw`.
The maximum size of the buffer parameter is 32767 bytes.

You check for `IF len < 32760 THEN`, however, I see no guarantee in your code, that the `len` variable actually holds the length of the `vblob` variable that is the buffer in the `put_raw` call.

So I suppose the `vblob` variable's actual length is longer then 32767 and that is the reason for the error.

Hence I suggest to delete this piece of code:

```
  IF len < 32760 THEN
    -- dbms_output.put_line('Single write ');
    utl_file.Put_raw(l_output, vblob);

    utl_file.Fflush(l_output);
  ELSE
```

also the `END IF;` of course, and always go for the 'write in pieces' branch.

I see now, you've done this based on the Burleson example which is good http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_writing_blob_clob_os_file.htm

but you see, unlike you, Burleson gets the len variable and the vblob variable from the same table and the same field.

```
-- get length of blob
SELECT dbms_lob.getlength(productblob)
INTO len
FROM products
WHERE id = product_id;

-- save blob length
x := len;

-- select blob into variable
SELECT product_blob
INTO vblob
FROM products
WHERE id = product_id;
```

**EDIT**

So an other option would be to fix the select for getting length. This means you'll have to  replace this select:

```
  -- get length of blob
  SELECT dbms_lob.Getlength(FILENAME)
  INTO   len
  FROM   GENERAL.GUBFILE
  WHERE  gubfile_name = pfname;
```

with this:

```
  -- get length of blob
  SELECT dbms_lob.Getlength(BLOBVALUE)
  INTO   len
  FROM   FILES
  WHERE  filename = pfname;
```

Comment: Fanstatic explanation!  Thank you very much. I made the change from select...filename to select...blobvalue and it worked! Can you please help me remove the WHERE? This way, we can grab all the files all at once?

Comment: @Chidi, thanks for the great feedback! If this issue has been solved, then I seriously suggest you to close this thread. It is clearly against SO principles to make a big messy spaghetti of a thread by adding new requests. 
If you want to write several blobs to files, then you have to open a cursor and call this procedure for every filename/displayname pairs returned by the cursor. Here's a little hint, how to do so, if it is not enough, then ask help about it in a new post. 

`for c in (select filename from FILES) loop
  getfile(c.filename, c.filename||'.txt');
end loop;`

Comment: Am I right in assuming that this will write the file to the file system on the host where the db is located, and not to the local drive where my client is running?

Comment: @Adam, you are correct. `utl_file` will create the file on the machine where the DB is hosted